# Combining shape & color legends in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, legend

When I plot the data below, I get 2 separate legends: factor(Type), relating to color, & factor(Category), relating to shape. I would like to have one legend (with no title) that represents both color & shape. Other StackOverflow solutions have not worked for me, please help!

```
library(sp)
library(sf) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggmap) 
library(dplyr)
```

Retrieve & format NYC area basemap

```
region.bb = c(left=-74.25,bottom=40.55,right=-73.7,top=40.97)
nyc.stamen <- get_stamenmap(bbox=region.bb,zoom=10,maptype="terrain-background")
```

Create data frame of coordinate data

```
Longitude <- c(-73.950311,-73.964482,-73.953678,-73.893522,-73.815856,-74.148499,-73.9465,-73.9585,-73.9223,-73.877744,-73.8796,-73.873983,-73.7781,-74.1745,-74.193432,-74.116770,-73.816316,-74.099108,-73.765924,-73.916045)
Latitude <- c(40.815313,40.767544,40.631762,40.872481,40.734335,40.604014,40.7315,40.8217,40.7905,40.837525,40.8105,40.776969,40.6413,40.6895,40.580011,40.773013,40.857311,40.744994,40.610648,40.799044)
Category <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7)
Type <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
coordinate.data <- data.frame(Longitude,Latitude,Type,Style,stringsAsFactors=F)
rownames(coordinate.data) <- c("METER","MANH","BKLN","BRON","QUEE","STAT","NEWTOWN_CREEK","NORTH_RIVER","WARDS_ISLAND","BUS_DEPOT","HUNTS_POINT","LGA","JFK","NJT","SITS","ERIE_NJ","BRONX_PELHAM","HUSDON","BAYSWATER","PP")
```

Plot points over NYC basemap

```
map.plot <- ggmap(nyc.stamen) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  geom_point(data=coordinate.data,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,color=factor(Type),shape=factor(Category)),size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(8,4,0,1,2,5,6,10)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","black")) +
theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill="white"),legend.key=element_rect(fill="white",color=NA))
print(map.plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you combine the color and shape legends when they both use the same variable as factor. In your case, color is a factor of `Type` and shape is a factor of `Category`. Combining them does not make any sense. My suggestion is to leave them with no title. While in your example there is a clear distinction of colors, you could have a red square and a black square, and in such a situation what should the legend display?

You can eliminate the legend title with statement

```
labs(x="Longitude" , y="Latitude" ,col=NULL, shape=NULL ) +
```

Also, you can combine the legends with the following statement:

```
guides(color="none", shape= guide_legend(override.aes=list(color=c("red","black") ))) +
```

My suggestion is not to do so.